# One tabBarItem draws two images occasionally

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

I can't figure out how did this happened.But there is something i have done may cause it.
1,I have swizzled `viewDidLoad` & `viewDidAppear` in `UIViewController`.

2,The `AppDelegate's` window's rootViewController is a mainViewController(`UIViewController`).
And I add customNavigationController.view to mainViewController.view.
`CustomNavigationController`'s rootViewController is a `UITabbarController`.

3,Thread problem?

4,This happened randomly when i tap and pan on the screen frequently.

Here is My code :
In my Custom `UITabBarController`

```
- (void)loadViewControllers {
    HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
    [homeVC.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home"]];
    [homeVC.tabBarItem setTitle:homeTab];

    ProductsViewController *productsVC = [[ProductsViewController alloc] init];
    [productsVC.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Products"]];
    [productsVC.tabBarItem setTitle:productsTab];

    DiscoverViewController *discoverVC = [[DiscoverViewController alloc] init];
    [discoverVC.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Discover"]];
    [discoverVC.tabBarItem setTitle:discoverTab];

    AssetsMainViewController *assetsVC = [[AssetsMainViewController alloc] init];
    [assetsVC.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Assets"]];
    [assetsVC.tabBarItem setTitle:assetsTab];

    NewsViewController *newsVC = [[NewsViewController alloc] init];
    [newsVC.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"News"]];
    [newsVC.tabBarItem setTitle:newsTab];
    [self setViewControllers:@[homeVC,productsVC, discoverVC, assetsVC, newsVC]];
}
```

In mainViewController:

```
- (void)loadViewController {

    TJSNavigationController *rootNavi = [[TJSNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[TJSTabBarController sharedSingleton]];

    [rootNavi.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tMeasure_Width_Sreen, tMeasure_Height_Screen)];
    [self.view addSubview:rootNavi.view];


    [[TJSTabBarController sharedSingleton] loadViewControllers];
    [[TJSTabBarController sharedSingleton] setDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: where did you set this icon, on your storyboard file or in your code. Can you share your code?

Comment: Can you check property of `assetsTab` on your storyboard?. Did you set value for it in this?

Comment: I didn't use storyboard